# Assert is returning true no matter the condition

Tags: php

For example, if I have

```
assert('2<1');
```

It turns out that the assertion returns as true. I also copy pasted Example #2 from http://php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php and it also evaluated every single assertion as true, when that's clearly not the case. Any idea what might be causing this?

Edit -

```
<?php
    var_dump(assert('2<1'));
?>
```

Output is

```
true
```

If i run this at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/, the assertion fails as expected. Yet this does not happen on my test server.

Edit #2 - 
PHP Version:

```
PHP 7.0.9-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.9-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Can't reproduce it. I get a warning for it. Please read [mcve].

Comment: Honestly a new php file with assert('2<1'); is passing for me. Literally just that code.

Comment: Have you tried to restart the server and or creating a new file and write it again?

Comment: Have you set correct assert options?

Comment: Maybe it is a interesting information which php version you are using.

Comment: Added php version to the question. Have restarted server, have created new file and tried anew. Assert options have been left both as default, and also with the settings in example #2 from the php docs which is linked in the op.

Comment: Not reproducible: https://3v4l.org/TkQc0

Comment: Check the output of `echo ini_get('zend.assertions');` is it `0` by any chance?

Comment: Are there any php.ini settings that I might need to change?

Comment: @Jon Stirling output was -1

Comment: Hmm, I can emulate your issue, but only when the value is 0. For settings look at the [Assertion] section in your PHP ini.

Comment: I take it back, I just got it for -1 as well...

Comment: Right, that makes some sense. -1 is "production". Change the value to `1` to enable asserts in development mode.

Comment: Yep just did so and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Gd gd, will write it up as an answer for those who don't read comments :P

Comment: :) I'll be standing by with my check mark!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assert's have 3 settings:

(exert from php.ini):

> -1: Do not compile at all
>   0: Jump over assertion at run-time
>   1: Execute assertions
>   ...
>   http://php.net/zend.assertions

-1 being "production", 1 being development and zero being an odd middle-ground that appears to act like production.

Apparently when in non-development mode this means that assert will always return true, effectively bypassing the check.